# How to password protect Scrapyd UI?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, scrapy, scrapyd

I have my website available to public and there is Scrapyd running at port 6800 like http://website.com:6800/

I do not want anyone to see list of my crawlers. I know anyone can easily guess type up port 6800 and can see whats going on.

I have few questions, answer any of them will help me.

1. Is there way to password protect Scrapyd UI?
2. Can I password protect a specific Port on Linux? I know it can be done with IPTables to ONLY ALLOW PARTICULAR IPs but thats not a good solution
3. Should I make changes to Scrapyd's source-code?
4. Can I password protect a specific port only via .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

You should [bind address](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#bind-address) of the machine that is going to make calls.

If its the localhost which is going to make calls to the endpoints just bind it to 127.0.0.1 and voila, the address doesn't work for external ips.

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest version of scrapyd (1.2.1 when am wrting this). Scrapyd support Basic HTTP Auth. Inorder to enable it just add username and password to scrapyd.conf as below

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd.git
```

```
[scrapyd]
eggs_dir          = /var/lib/scrapyd/eggs

...
username    = username_here
password    = password_here
...
```

Comment: I tried, it doesnt work, and also, its no where in their Docs.

Comment: Hmm, its actually this fork https://github.com/my8100/scrapyd has auth supported, not from scrapyd

Comment: @UmairAyub It is there in the official repo
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/master/scrapyd/basicauth.py

Answer (score 0):

As of scrapyd version 1.2.0 the default [bind address](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.0/config.html#bind-address) is 127.0.0.1

To add a password protection use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/wvengen/ec5c795b0f2960d7ea07) which uses nginx as a reverse proxy to add basic authentication to scrapyd.

You may also check [scrapyd-authenticated](https://github.com/cdrx/scrapyd-authenticated) repository.